# How to hide an app from play store for a couple of hours

Tags: google-play, app-store, google-play-console

Due to a migration in the back I would like to temporary stop my app from being downloaded.

In the past I could manage that in Play Store Console. But now I can't find any switch for that.

How to disable the app temporary in Play Store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Playstore developer console You can go to pricing and distribution section in the left hand side panel

You should find Availability section listing lot of countries where your app would be available for download from playstore

You can make all countries as unavailable or few selected countries

for keeping you app hidden from playstore and there by stopping downloads from playstore for sometime , you can always make your app available by selecting available in countries once done available , your app would be back in playstore within few minutes and will be ready for download.

Comment: But then you have to remember all the countries you have previously selected. In the past I remember there was one simple switch to turn off availibility for one app. It seems to be gone ?

Comment: @mcflysoft  Yes i guess there is a turn off switch , guess it is gone now 

But here in this case he does not need to remember anything , as he will make it unavailable for all countries for couple of hours and bring it back to all once he is done

#all or none

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an answer, it is possible nowadays (an easier and better way than the other answer suggests).

1. First open up Google Play Console
2. On the left hand side click `Setup` > `Advanced Settings`

[image]

3. Then under `App Availability` click `Unpublished`

[image]